# Insert data into teable variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data through my stored procedure and finding difficulty in doing it.

I tried doing below code but it doesn't work.

```
    DECLARE @AddressRecordsToPurge TABLE  
    (  
      RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),  
      GUIDValue Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
      GuidColumn Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
      GuidTable Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL  
    )

    Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge values ( Select AccountGUID FROM APPLICATIONCONTRACT  WHERE ApplicationNumber =@ApplicationNumber AND AccountGUID IS NOT NULL, 'AccountGUID', 'PREVIOUSLENDERSREF');
```

my first value is query and last 2 values are strings. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge (GUIDValue, GuidColumn, GuidTable)
    Select AccountGUID, 'AccountGUID', 'PREVIOUSLENDERSREF'
    from APPLICATIONCONTRACT 
    where ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber and
          AccountGUID IS NOT NULL;
```

Notes:

- This explicitly lists the columns being inserted.
- The `identity` column is not in the list, so it will get the default value.
- There is no need for `values`, just `insert . . . select`.

As for your code, you need to remember that a subquery always needs to be surrounded by its own set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Alias string names as column names. When you declare a `table variable` you do not need to mention column names for insert unless you are inserting into few columns. `Identity column` will automatically populate.

```
DECLARE @AddressRecordsToPurge TABLE  
    (  
      RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),  
      GUIDValue Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
      GuidColumn Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
      GuidTable Nvarchar(max) NOT NULL  
    )

    Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge 
      SELECT
      AccountGUID  AS GUIDValue
     ,'AccountGUID'  AS GuidColumn
     ,'PREVIOUSLENDERSREF' AS GuidTable
     FROM APPLICATIONCONTRACT  
     WHERE ApplicationNumber =@ApplicationNumber AND AccountGUID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To This Way:

```
 DECLARE @AddressRecordsToPurge TABLE
        (
          RowID INT NOT NULL
                    PRIMARY KEY
                    IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
          GUIDValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL ,
          GuidColumn NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL ,
          GuidTable NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
        ) 

        INSERT  INTO @AddressRecordsToPurge
                ( GUIDValue ,
                  GuidColumn ,
                  GuidTable
                )
                SELECT  AccountGUID ,
                        'AccountGUID' ,
                        'PREVIOUSLENDERSREF'
                FROM    APPLICATIONCONTRACT AS artp
                WHERE   ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber
                        AND AccountGUID IS NOT NULL
```